# Sencha touch reset file field

Tags: file, extjs, touch, field, reset

I'm using a filefield in my sencha touch application and I'm not able to reset this field. The clear icon doesn't work if I click it and `form.reset()` doesn't affect the file field. I'm using sencha touch 2.4.1 and I'm testing it on Chrome browser and Safari Mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `field.getComponent().input.dom.value = "";` for reseting file field.